# Copying folder and subfiles/folders via terminal.

Tags: files, copy

To start this off, I've always been a windows user so I feel like I'm in over my head right now and will probably come off as ignorant, so my apologies.

My goal is to copy a windows store app folder and subfiles/folders from my external hard drive to my internal hard drive.

I have pretty slow and data capped internet,only 100gb per month for myself and 3 people that just chew through data. I bought and wanted to download a game (55gb) and took my laptop to a nearby Cafe who kindly allowed me to download it there, but there's no way to just copy/paste the files over from laptop to desktop due to encryption.

My idea was to try Ubuntu for the first time ever to just copy/paste the folder by just not using a windows OS and thus having the best chance to bypass the encryption.

Ubuntu is installed on a hard drive by itself, the game files are on an external USB hard drive and I would like to copy them to a large internal hard drive that I use for storage.

A straight copy paste from 1 drive to another just came up with "permission denied" errors for every file

So far I found and tried "gksudo nautilus" to allow a GUI copy paste but it wouldn't work and needed to install "sudo apt-get gksu" which could not locate the package. Or "sudo apt-get update" which returned a Heap of err 404 lines, failed to fetch lines and ended with E: some index files failed to download.

I then found "sudo -i" that said to give root access via the terminal, so I tried that followed by "rsync - av /media/user/Seagate\ External\ Drive/WUDownloadCache/gamefiles /media/user/Internal\ Storage/WUDownloadCache" which, to my lack-of-knowledge should copy "gamefiles" from the external drive to "WUDoenloadCache" on the internal drive but came back with the same errors as just trying to copy and paste via the GUI. Permission denied, for every single file.

I'm 100% certain I'm doing something wrong, any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: What Ubuntu version is this, as I use Ubuntu Xenial and I ran `apt search gksu` and found the package you say wasn't there?

Comment: The error `err 404 lines` has to do with internet so check your connection and try again!

Comment: I just grabbed 15.10 because I only intended to run the "try ubuntu" feature off my USB flash drive. When it came up saying it could not locate the package I then installed it to a hard drive I had sitting around, figuring that only basic features working when testing the OS. The strange thing is, I could use Firefox just fine for whatever I needed but running the update command from terminal would run to 21% and would hang, then come up with errors.

Comment: -update- I opened Firefox again and searched gksu package to see if I could manually install it. Found it from Ubuntu.com it had a dependancy for libgksu so I searched and got that, which needed libgtop which I also searched and got. Opening the terminal I ran gksu nautilus which opened the file manager gui. Copy and pasted the folder and still got "error splicing file: permission denied" for each file. Same thing if I run "sudo -i" before running "gksu nautilus". Other files will copy and paste just fine. Regardless of wifi or ethernet connection sudo apt-get update will not complete.

Comment: Please grab the latest that version is EOL and some of the repos will be down permanently!